# Flutter Redux Persistent doesn't store Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, redux

I have following AppState:

```
class AppState {
  String token;
  Map<String, dynamic> authUser;

  AppState({
    this.token = "",
    this.authUser,
  });

  AppState.fromAppState(AppState other) {
    token = other.token;
    authUser = other.authUser;
  }

  static AppState fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return json != null
        ? AppState(
            token: json["token"],
            authUser: json["auth_user"],
          )
        : AppState();
  }

  dynamic toJson() => {
        "token": token,
        "auth_user": authUser,
      };
}
```

As you can see, the state stores the JWT of the authenticated user and his data (id, username, email).
These values are set after successful signup:

```
StoreConnector<AppState, Map<String, Function>>(
converter: (store) => {
  "token": (String newToken) =>
      store.dispatch(actions.Token(newToken)),
  "auth_user": (Map<String, dynamic> authUser) =>
      store.dispatch(actions.AuthUser(authUser)),
},
builder: (ctx, setAppState) => FlatButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    if (username.value.text.isEmpty ||
        email.value.text.isEmpty ||
        password.value.text.isEmpty ||
        !widget.formKey.currentState.validate())
      return;
    setState(() => loading = true);
    try {
      final String token = await Api.signup(
        username: username.text,
        email: email.text,
        password: password.text,
      );
      setAppState["token"](token);
      setAppState["auth_user"](
          await Api.authUser(token: token));
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Home(),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          content: Text(e.toString()),
        ),
      );
    } finally {
      setState(() => loading = false);
    }
  },
  child: Text(
    AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .get("signup_label"),
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 21,
    ),
  ),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      width: 3,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(25),
    ),
  ),
),
),
```

In brief, when I sign up, the token and auth_user are set in the state and can be used on the home screen.
However, if I restart the app, it turns out, only token is persistent and auth_user is set to null by default.
I'm very new to flutter and redux, so maybe I made an obvious mistake.

Reducer:

```
AppState reducer(AppState prevState, dynamic action) {
  AppState newState = AppState.fromAppState(prevState);

  if (action is Token) {
    newState.token = action.token;
  }

  if (action is AuthUser) {
    newState.authUser = action.user;
  }

  return newState;
}
```

Actions:

```
class Token {
  final String token;
  Token(this.token);
}

class AuthUser {
  final Map<String, dynamic> user;
  AuthUser(this.user);
}
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

I just found the bug:
In the constructor, I was missing the this keyword in front of authUser.